# How to create Wordpress search buttons for a single book title within several external digital platforms?

Tags: wordpress, button, search, widget, product

**1. THE CONTEXT**

As indie authors, we have a Wordpress website presenting each of our books, which are sold on several digital platforms and in different languages. We do not sell our books directly on our website and do not intend to do so in the near future.

Each book is presented on a single html-php-generated page which has the same html title as the book itself, and contains the full description of the mentioned book, as well as the actual cover shown as a "featured image".

**2. THE PROBLEM**

To help our website visitors find a specific book of their choosing on their preferred platform, I would like to insert on each book page a "search button" for each platform (say: Amazon, Kobo, Apple...) generating a search command URL on the respective digital platform, opening on a _blank new html page (the output would be, say: search on the Amazon website for "book" and "author").

This way, it would be easy for our visitors (coming from our website's book page) to "jump" and find the respective book and eventually buy it DIRECTLY on their preferred selling-platform, using the famous auto-generated search buttons.

**3. THE GUESS**

I am not a coding specialist (how to code that: html, javascript, php??) and would love to put it easily as a Wordpress widget for example (a "single product / many platforms crawling utility search buttons"), but my guess would be that each "search button" would sequentially:

1. retrieve the html title page (which has the same name as the book title)
2. add to the retrieved html title the author's name
3. generate a simple html search command to open a new _blank page on a digital platform performing the "(book title)+(author's name)" search request and... voilà!

Well... that is the idea :-)
But... I cannot do it myself for the time being... (boo hoo!)

I would like to thank you in advance for your kind help and generosity if you provide a solution!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally found a solution:

First, download this WordPress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-widget/

Then, type this kind of code in it:

```
<?php 
echo "<a href = \"https://www.amazon.com/s?k=". get_the_title($ID)." Cristina Rebiere"."\" target='_blank'>Amazon</a>";
?>
```

and so on for other platforms...
Cheers!